# Excel VBA that works like scheduling assistant of Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

'm really new at creating VBA codes and cannot write one alone. Is it possible to create a VBA code that works like Outlook's scheduling assistant? I want it to work like the scheduling assistant. I tried freebusy but it shows "Object does not support this method"

Im at this part where i can send the details using excel info.

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub AddAppointments()

      Dim myoutlook As Object ' Outlook.Application
      Dim r As Long
      Dim myapt As Object ' Outlook.AppointmentItem
      Dim time As String

      ' late bound constants
      Const olAppointmentItem = 1
      Const olBusy = 2
      Const olMeeting = 1

      ' Create the Outlook session
      Set myoutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

      ' Start at row 2
      r = 2

      Do Until Trim$(Cells(r, 1).Value) = ""
        ' Create the AppointmentItem
        Set myapt = myoutlook.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
        ' Set the appointment properties
        With myapt
          .Subject = Cells(2, 1).Value
          .Location = Cells(3, 1).Value
          .Start = Cells(4, 1).Value
          time = .Start
          .Duration = Cells(5, 1).Value
          .Recipients.Add Cells(8, 1).Value & ";" & _
          Cells(8, 2).Value & ";" & _
          Cells(8, 3).Value & ";" & _
          Cells(8, 4).Value & ";" & _
          Cells(8, 5).Value & ";" & _
          Cells(8, 6).Value & ";" & _
          Cells(8, 7).Value & ";" & _
          Cells(8, 8).Value & ";" & _
          Cells(8, 9).Value & ";" & _
          Cells(8, 10).Value

          .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
          ' not necessary if recipients are email addresses
          myapt.Recipients.ResolveAll
          'myapt.Recipients.FreeBusy = "(#8/8/2015#, 60, False)"
         ' .AllDayEvent = Cells(9, 1).Value

          ' If Busy Status is not specified, default to 2 (Busy)
          If Len(Trim$(Cells(5, 1).Value)) = 0 Then
            .BusyStatus = olBusy
          Else
            .BusyStatus = Cells(5, 1).Value
          End If

          If Cells(6, 1).Value > 0 Then
            .ReminderSet = True
            .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = Cells(6, 1).Value
          Else
            .ReminderSet = False
          End If

          .Body = Cells(7, 1).Value
          .Save
          r = r + 1
          .Display
        End With
      Loop
    End Sub
```

Comment: So which line throws that error?

Comment: 'myapt.Recipients.FreeBusy = "(#8/8/2015#, 60, False)" This line throws the error. Seems that it needs some tweaking and it doesn't get the FreeBusy Time of multiple recipients

Answer (score 0):

FreeBusy method is implemented by the Recipient object. You can calling that method on the Recipients (note the plural "s") object. Loop through all recipients and call FreeBusy on each recipient.

Or use the Recipient object returned by the Recipients.Add

It also looks that you pass multiple recipients separated by ";" to a call to Recipients.Add. You must call Recipients.Add for each recipient. Or you can set the To property instead (it allows multiple recipients separated by ";").

Comment: I'm not really good at excel vba, if possible could you send a sample code for your explanation

Comment: For which part? Adding multiple recipients? Or calling FreeBusy?

Comment: For both. I kinda can picture out how to call multiple receipients but I'm ending up doing it individually. For freebusy. If possible i would like to match the Freebusy for each recipient.

Comment: There is no way to retrieve free/busy for multiple recipients in a single call in the Outlook Object Model. You have to do that one recipient at a time.

Comment: Then how should I do it?

Comment: Loop through all recipients, call FreeBusy for each one of them, merge the returned data.